# Запрет на доступ к файлу в Битриксе почему не работает?

Tags: битрикс

Выставляю все запрещено, а в другом браузере под анонимом все равно файл загружается.

Что не так? Только этого мало, где еще сделать запреты?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Файл html это статика, потому права доступа на него не действуют, он не подключает ядро битрикс. Потому запрещать такой файл надо в htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего дело в том, что вы используете html файл.  Т.е. nginx отдает его как старику в обход Apache. Вы можете определить кто отдает контент в по HTTP заголовком ответа. Или просто сделать тоже самое для index.php . 
Если теория подтверждается, то запрет к файла нужно делать на уровне nginx.